# Why there is this error: unexpected null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1SNz.png)I followed a YouTube tutorial to connect OpenAI to a Flutter Flow application with the goal of creating a chatbot. I followed all the steps, but when I launch the test, either a blank gray page appears or an error page with an error message.

I watched the tutorial again and followed all the steps exactly, but the issue still persists.
If you have another way to create a chatbot with OpenAI or if you have a solution, please help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Share HomePageWidget code,

Getting this error because you are showing something on UI which is null for eg.

```
String? data; // here data == null
Text(data!) // show error in UI
```

The solution is :
**1 Give your variable some initial value**

```
String data = ""; // hence data != null
Text(data) // shows nothing because string is empty, not null
```

**2 OR Use if else condition like below**

```
String? data; // here data == null
Text(data ?? "no data found") // shows no data found in UI
```

*Happy Coding :)*